# how to get reference to the current window from async task? Android

Tags: android, user-interface, window

In my application, i use tabs and it has settings, home etc tabs. In settings page there is a textview with some text. In home page there is an async task which runs in background.

Now what i want is, when user is watching settings page, and if the async task from home.java class completes doInBackground method, i want to update the textview in settings page.

How can i get the reference of the textview of settings page in the onPostExecute method of async task in home.class? Please give some clues or ways to implement this..

thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't try to access the TextView directly from the onPostExecute() method of your AsyncTask. Instead temporally store the value you want to set to the TextView somewhere centrally, and retrieve it from there when the settings page is accessed.

To store the value you can use different mechanism. If you don't need to persist it, you can use a singleton class which can be accessed from very where within you application. To persist the value you should use the [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), a file or a database.

Check [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more informations.

Comment: i want the textview to be updated dynamically(after the completion of doInBackground) when the user is on settings page itself..

Comment: i can put a thread in the settings.class to update the field for every certain time. but i didn't want like that.. I want to access the textview from another class(home.java) is it possible? Something like getCurrentFocus etc..

Comment: @manidhar mulaparthi: "I want to access the textview from another class(home.java) is it possible?" -- that is not a good idea. Please follow the recommendations provided by @Flo.

Comment: thank you, but i am already using database to store that value and displaying the textview by retrieving that. If i reenter the settings page, it gets updated. But what i want is dynamic property. I don't want the user to re enter the settings page to get the updated textview..

Comment: Implement some kind of [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) which informs your settings activity when the value got updated. So you need a component (e.g. a singleton class) which is used to update the value in the database and then notifies listener registered to it about the update. Your settings activity would be such a listener. By this way you're settings activity gets informed about the new value and can retrieve it and update the UI. As it makes only sense to notify when you activity is visible it should register in onResume() and unregister in onPause().